# IE doesn't parse xml response text using jquery's find() properly

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

Good Morning,

I have a really simple script that works fine on everything but IE. I'm populating a dropdown menu with information from a database using an XML response in the following format:

```
<options>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
...
</options>
```

I'm getting this data like so:

```
var options = $.ajax({
          url     :   "/static/scripts/php/search.php",
          type    :   "POST",
          data    :   {search_key :   key}
      }).responseText;
```

And the response is coming back just fine, regardless of browser. IE and Chrome alert the response text the same.

But when I do:

```
 $(options).find('option').each(function() {
         var option = document.createElement('option');
         $(option).attr("value", $(this).text()).text($(this).text());
         $(select).append(option);
     });
```

IE never enters the each() loop, meaning it's not finding "option" in the response text. I'm at my wit's end with this. It's too simple of a script to be spending this much time on. Any help?

I've run the script through JSLint looking for small, odd items, and it's clean.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responseText is a string, try parsing it as xml first.

```
options = $.parseXML(responseText);
```

Also, generally you don't want to use the response text in that way. It is usually best to use the done callback or success callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  ...
  dataType: "xml", // so that it will auto parse it as xml
  success: function(xml){
    // do something with xml
  }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  ...
  dataType: "xml" // so that it will auto parse it as xml
}).done(function(xml){
  // do something with xml
});
```

Comment: Changing it to a callback worked. It got extra mad when I tried parseXml. Thanks.

Comment: When you use the response text the way you were, it should return undefined because the request hadn't been made yet.

Comment: I use async:false in the ajax call. I know that doing that means I may as well just render it all via PHP, but the jquery syntax is just a lot easier to contend with, and the boss wanted it superfast. It's just something used internally by my dept.

Comment: Granted, that shortcut wound up not being so short after all. /grin

Comment: As far as why it didn't work by simply using $(xml) where xml is your xml string, using $(xml) parses the xml as html. Since the tags used within are not valid html elements, IE ignores them.